# Can't open C# files in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After A normal restart of my computer, i was trying to create a normal Console Application in Visual Studio 2013. Then the project is created. Then it tries to open the Program.cs Notepad open and says Access Denied. Any have the same problem.

Comment: Did you try with _run as administrator_ ?

Comment: Any chance you've accidentally told Windows to always open csproj or sln in notepad? (via Open With...)

Comment: @MarcGravell I have look in the specific file, which was the standard program for using the file. It's said Vs2012.

Comment: The problem was that for some reason the folder that the projects was located, VS2013 haven't got access to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem to the issue was some internal file directive.

Comment: It would be nice for the rest of us with this problem if you'd have included what the fix was. Your answer is not an answer.